# Limit the number of digits used/printed in R in ANY context

Tags: r, significant-digits

Is there any way of limiting the number of digits R displays in *any* context? I have tried everything, including `options(digits = 3)`.

Take a look at this output from my code (*after* calling `options(digits = 3)`):

`compute(NN, cbind(Test_cv[,c("Activity", "Annualised_15")], (Test_cv[, "Activity"]^2), (Test_cv[, "Annualised_15"]^2)  ) )`

Output:

```
$neurons[[2]]
    [,1]      [,2]     [,3]                                                                                                        [,4]
12     1 0.9999202 0.000015 0.000000000000000005288370990993990868565821639180057900375686585903167724609375000000000000000000000000000
13     1 0.9991250 0.619258 0.000000000000013876853661493364176966747169927884897333569824695587158203125000000000000000000000000000000
35     1 0.0000727 0.003018 0.032829945321210009245849192893729195930063724517822265625000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Columns two and three are already too much, but column four is just insane!

`scipen` is not what I want either - setting it to low values gives me scientific notation:

```
options(scipen = 2, digits = 3)
compute(NN, cbind(Test_cv[,c("Activity", "Annualised_15")], (Test_cv[, "Activity"]^2), 
                  (Test_cv[, "Annualised_15"]^2)  ) )
```

Output:

```
    [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]   
12     1 0.9999202 0.000015  5.29e-18 
13     1 0.9991250 0.619258  1.39e-14
```

I just want this:

```
    [,1]      [,2]     [,3]      [,4]   
12     1      0.99     0.00      0.00 
13     1      0.99     0.62      0.00
```

Anywhere, any time.

How do I limit this at the start of the session to stop this happening anywhere at any time *without* having to use `round()` or `signif()` or `sprintf()` or `formatC()` all the time and wrapping every single piece of code in one of these functions?

p.s. I haven't included a reproducible example because I'm sure lots of people have seen this kind of thing and it's a very general question.

Many, many thanks to anyone who can answer this.

Comment: Probably `sprintf("%0.2f", 0.00000000000000000528837)` will work if it's just for display. This function returns a character vector. Or the related `formatC(0.00000000000000000528837, digits=2, format="f")`.

Comment: I'm looking for a UNIVERSAL solution so that I don't have to keep wrapping my code in those kind of one-off functions like formatC() or sprintf(). Surely I can, at the start of the session just call a function that goes I_Only_Want_to_see_x_Numbers(3) and I don't have to worry about it for the rest of the script/session.